# Is merge a proper way in this scenario?

Tags: git

There is a `branchA`constantly being developed and new commits being created. Maybe 20 commits ago, we created a `branchB`with a feature that was supposed to be finished later on.

Now, that we are starting work on `branchB`, should I merge changed from `branchA`into `branchB`?

If yes, shall I do the same in a few days?

The root of confusion is the fact that both `branchA` and `branchB` are being constantly developed on and new commits made, so I am not sure if merging `branchA` into `branchB` every day is a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally all developers should `sync` their branch with `default-branch (normally master)`. As `branchA` and `branchB` are developing continuously and if you don't need `branchA` changes then don't merge that.

After `branchA` feature is done and merged with `default-branch` (master), pull the `master` branch into `branchB` (would get `branchA` changes).

**Rebase:** if you want to pull `branchA` frequently into `branchB` then reabasing would be good choice.

```
$ git checkout branchB
$ git rebase branchA                # keep branchB changes top
```

Comment: you should also mention that rebasing the branchB is necessary in this particular example.

Comment: @stdcall ok. I added rebasing part.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go for:

```
git checkout branchB
git rebase branchA
```

Which will do the merge and put all the commits in `branchB` on top of those made in `branchA`. It's explained really well here: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing

**One caveat though**: if there are several people working on `branchB` you have to agree on the time when you're doing the rebase, as you'll have to `push --force` your rebased branch to the remote which might result in:

- Another developers commits being overwritten (who pushed them in while you were doing the rebasing)
- Putting a developer who has some commits on his local `branchB` into an awkward situation when trying to `pull branchB` (rebased) from `origin`. To get back in-sync with the branch local commits will have to be cherry-picked into the new `branchB`